# Why is only last clicked like/heart changes color like intended and the others stay in normal colour?

Tags: php, laravel

I made a like/favorite button (heart) and want it to go blue when you click it. This works fine, except when you click another heart, the first heart that was blue turns white again, and only the last clicked heart turns blue.

Every time you click on another heart, only the last clicked heart turns blue! The rest works fine, but I don't know why this happens. Anybody?

```
class Products extends Component
{
    public $orderBy;
    public $vacid;
   
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->orderBy = "Sorteer: Nieuwste Vacatures";

        if(Auth::id()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $fav = Favoriet::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();
        foreach($fav as $fav){
            $this->vacid = $fav->vacature_id;
        }
    }
}
```

```
     @if($vac->id == $vacid)
          <a class="bi bi-heart-fill fa-lg m-2" href="{{url('favorieten',$vac->id)}}" 
           data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Voeg toe aan favorieten">
          </a>
@else
<a class="bi bi-heart fa-lg m-2" href="{{url('favorieten',$vac->id)}}" 
           data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Voeg toe aan favorieten">
          </a>
          @endif
          <div class="border"></div>
          @endforeach 
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up images of code; code is TEXT and belongs in a codeblock in your question

Comment: Please recheck the template code, there is a rogue `@endforeach` in the current snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ensures that all liked items are stored in the `$this->vacids` array, and you can then check if the current `$vac->id` is in that array. This way, each liked item will retain its blue color after being clicked.

```
class Products extends Component
{
    public $orderBy;
    public $vacids = []; // Change to array
   
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->orderBy = "Sorteer: Nieuwste Vacatures";

        if (Auth::id()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $fav = Favoriet::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
            foreach ($fav as $fav) {
                $this->vacids[] = $fav->vacature_id; // Store all $vac->id values in an array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// ...

@if (in_array($vac->id, $this->vacids))
    <a class="bi bi-heart-fill fa-lg m-2" href="{{url('favorieten',$vac->id)}}" 
        data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Voeg toe aan favorieten">
    </a>
@else
    <a class="bi bi-heart fa-lg m-2" href="{{url('favorieten',$vac->id)}}" 
        data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Voeg toe aan favorieten">
    </a>
@endif
```